# PXE boot uefi only using proxy dhcp

Tags: dhcp, pxe, dnsmasq

I'm trying to setup PXE booting and so far I can only boot in CSM mode. All my machines are UEFI capable so I only need to support UEFI.

When I try to network boot in UEFI mode `>> Start PXE over IPv4` comes on the screen and then nothing happens. I can't find much documentation or guides on PXE booting in UEFI mode with proxy dhcp.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the PXE servers out there are not ready for PXE booting UEFI NBPs (Network Boot Program) instead they try to load the classic i.e. pxelinux.0 which is a "BIOS only" NBP.

UEFI/BIOS capable PXE servers are able to detect the booting client PreOS firmware mode (BIOS/CSM, UEFI 64, UEFI 32) and provide the corresponding NBP.

WDS, MDT, [Serva](http://vercot.com/~serva/an/WindowsPXE1.html), etc are all PXE servers able to boot UEFI clients. (I'm related to Serva Development)

If you need it on a Linux environment you have to do it manually configuring your DHCP and defining your NBP startegy i.e. pxelinux.0/syslinux.efi (64)/ syslinux.efi (32)